How to Find Overlapping Epoch Ranges in a Dataframe
I have a very large dataframe that includes a categorical column with multiple categories and an epoch column associating each category with a number of epochs. I am trying to determine all of the epoch ranges where ALL of the categories overlap. The data is not always measured in a consistent manner, so the epochs do not necessarily match 1 to 1.
My thought was to make a table with columns for epoch and each category and have a row for each epoch within the timeframe and merge my data to the nearest epoch to find where all categories are overlapping, but this is obviously a horribly inefficient way to do it.
Below is a sample dataframe and output.
    type  number (epoch)
0      0             500
1      0             510
2      0             520
3      0             530
4      0             540
5      0             550
6      0             560
7      0             570
8      0             720
9      0             730
10     0             740
11     0             750
12     0             760
13     0             770
14     0             780
15     0            1000
16     0            1010
17     0            1020
18     0            1030
19     1             450
20     1             470
21     1             490
22     1             510
23     1             530
24     1             550
25     1             570
26     1             590
27     1             610
28     1             630
29     1             650
30     1             670
31     1             690
32     1             710
33     1             730
34     1             750
35     1             770
36     1             790
37     1             810
38     1             830
39     1             850
40     1             870
41     1             890
42     1             910
43     1             930
44     1             950
45     1             970
46     1             990
47     1            1010
48     1            1030
49     1            1050
50     1            1070
51     2             520
52     2             530
53     2             540
54     2             730
55     2             740
56     2             750
57     2             760
58     2            1100
59     2            1110
60     2            1120
61     2            1130
62     2            1140
63     2            1150
64     2            1160
65     2            1170
66     2            1180

Sample Output
  overlap ranges  Time Difference
0        520-540               20
1        730-760               30


And what is the expected output for this dataframe?

The epoch range(s) where all categories are overlapping. Which I'm now realizing may be none for my sample data...

Share a small sample dataframe with expected output dataframe

Updated the data and added a sample output for everyone.

"The data is not always measured in a consistent manner" - Then how do you tell what constitutes a "range"? It seems to be consistent per type, is that correct?

It is not always consistent per type. It usually is, but it can sometimes switch up a little bit. I would consider any period without a major jump to be a range.

Your question is not clear; for instance what's exactly Time Difference in the Sample Output? Either way, this might work:
epoch_type_count = df.groupby("number (epoch)")["type"].nunique()
epoch_type_count[epoch_type_count == 3]


This would only account for individual values where there is a data point, but not for ranges where individual points fall between.
